# Alter source with webpack plugin

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to write a webpack plugin that accumulates js require/import calls matching a certain pattern, removes them from the source before they are resolved (because resolution will fail) and then passes the accumulated information along to separate bundle-building process. How would one go about modifying source with a plugin?  Furthermore, is a plugin even the right approach for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `input => output` pattern you described there is more of the behavior of a Webpack loader.

## What is a Webpack Loader?

A webpack ***loader*** in its simplest form is a function which takes a `source` argument, and then must return a source:

```
function allySimpleButAwesomeWebpackLoader(source) {
  var yingSources = source + 'SomeString';

  return yingSources; 
}
```

---

## What is a Webpack Plugin?

A Plugin does everything a loader can't. I like referring people to the [ProgressPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/ProgressPlugin.js#L5-L132) - which is part of the webpack lib - when they want to learn how to implement the lifecycle hooks for a webpack plugin.

A ***plugin*** in its simplest form is an ES5 OOP Function with one prototype method `apply`. This apply function gets supplied a `compiler` variable which serves as access to the Compiler API.

```
function AllyAwesomePlugin(optionsObject) {
  this.pluginOptions = optionsObject;    


}

AllyAwesomePlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {

}
```

---

[Here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/how-to-write-a-plugin) is some great documentation on how to write a Webpack Plugin and more information about the Webpack Compiler/Plugin API.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that a loader will only work if the requested path can be found by the standard node_modules lookup logic?  In this particular situation I'm trying to load something like require('some.namespace') instead of the usual require('path/to/module').  Additional logic is needed to resolve some.namespace to a file path.  Based on your explanation and further reading I think a plugin is needed for this.  What do you think?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like a loader may be the desired approach.

Comment: What would be the plugin equivalent to the above loader? Would it be possible to have some sort of souce-to-source mapping with a plugin?